# what is the fractal dimension of the henon map?

Tags: fractals

I have some questions about the Henon map that are not clear for me. I have seen that the correlation dimension of the Henon map is approximately 1,21, is that measure similar to its fractal dimension?

Also, can the Henon map could be considered like a multifractal? I am using a program that measures the multifractal spectra and the maximum value of Q, sometimes it is 1,21, when I rerun the program it can be 1,27 and when I run it again it can be also 1,31, why is that change?

That multifractal program measures the multifractal spectra based on the figure of the henon map

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

The maximum value of of the f(alpha) spectrum occurs at the value of alpha for which Q=0.  The alpha(Q) spectrum is numerically derived from the generalized dimension spectrum, D(Q).  The D(Q) spectrum is calculated from the slope of a log-log plot of experimental data (related to the sum over some probability distribution raised to the power Q vs boxsize).

The value of the maximum can change depending on which portion of data is linearly fit, as the slope of the line will be different.